# Tcolorboxes in itemize: additional vertical spacing in first item

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, itemize, tcolorbox

Consider following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newtcolorbox{zitat}[2][]{%
    breakable, % IMPORTANT
    colback=block-gray,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{gray},
    title={#2\par},
    colbacktitle={block-gray},
    coltitle={black},
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    attach title to upper={},
    box align=top,
    #1,
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Quotes} % commenting removes difference
\begin{itemize}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 1}
    Space: the final frontier.
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which produces following output

[image]

As you can see there is more vertical space before tcolorbox in the first item compared to the last two ones.

This disappears when I remove the section command.

What can I do to fix this without manually adjusting it?

(TexLive 2016 on OSX El Capitan, tcolorbox 2016/11/18 version 3.96)

**UPDATE**:

It appears that the option `breakable` is responsible. There is a related option `vfill before first`:

> `/tcb/vfill before first=true|false` Inserts a `\vfill` at the begin of
>   the first partial box to move this partial box to the end of the
>   current page. This may be used as an alternative to `/tcb/height fixed`
>   `for=first` to get justified columns or pages. The `\vfill` is not
>   inserted, if the box gets not actually broken.

However, removing `breakable` and inserting a `\vfill` does not reproduce this issue. I guess the author of `tcolorbox` probably knows what is going on.

I report this to https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues

Comment: I'm sorry, but *this* code produces a normal spacing for me. You must have something else in your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I removed randomly the option `breakable` to avoid vertical scrolling on tex.stackexchange.com which appears to be responsible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcolorbox` takes special care to insert the right spacing after a heading. This is especially tricky, if the `tcolorbox` should be breakable, because breakable boxes always start a new paragraph. Putting this combination into a list environment like `itemize` seems to be too much for the algorithm.

Currently, I would'nt know how to handle this automatically without risking to break other mechanisms.

But, there are (at least) two ways to avoid the situation.

**Way 1:**

Add a `\@nobreakfalse` after your section heading. This will switch off the special treatment for headings which has a bad effect here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newtcolorbox{zitat}[2][]{%
    breakable, % IMPORTANT
    colback=block-gray,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{gray},
    title={#2\par},
    colbacktitle={block-gray},
    coltitle={black},
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    attach title to upper={},
    box align=top,
    #1,
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Quotes} 
\makeatletter\@nobreakfalse\makeatother%
\begin{itemize}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 1}
    Space: the final frontier.
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Way 2:**

Add an `ignore nobreak` option to the first of your `zitat` environments after the heading. Alternatively, this could be added to the general option list of your environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newtcolorbox{zitat}[2][]{%
    breakable, % IMPORTANT
    colback=block-gray,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{gray},
    title={#2\par},
    colbacktitle={block-gray},
    coltitle={black},
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    attach title to upper={},
    box align=top,
    %  ignore nobreak,  %<---- could also be added here
    #1,
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Quotes} 
\begin{itemize}
  \item \begin{zitat}[ignore nobreak]{Quote 1}      
    Space: the final frontier.
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
  \item \begin{zitat}{Quote 2}
    A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away\ldots
  \end{zitat}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Both ways should give the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I've added `ignore nobreak` to the first `zitat`.